# GORM: null check on new property leads to QueryException

Tags: grails-orm, isnull, executequery

I've added a new property `uuid` into the GORM mapping of the formerly existing domain class BComponent:

```
static mapping = {
  tablePerHierarchy false
  id column:'bc_id'
  uuid column:'bc_uuid', type:'text'
  name column:'bc_name', type:'text', index:'bc_name_idx'
  normname column:'bc_normname', type:'text', index:'bc_normname_idx'
  version column:'bc_version'
  // ... other properties
}
```

When it comes to executing code dealing this new property in BootStrap.groovy, like...

```
BComponent.withTransaction() {
  BComponent.executeQuery("select bc.id from BComponent as bc where bc.uuid is null").each { bc_id ->
    BComponent.withNewTransaction {
      BComponent bc = BComponent.get(bc_id)
      bc.generateUuid()
      bc.save()
      bc.discard()
    }
  }
}
```

... the following Exception is thrown:

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: could not resolve property: uuid of: org.gokb.cred.BComponent [select bc.id from org.gokb.cred.BComponent as bc where bc.uuid is null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: uuid of: org.gokb.cred.BComponent [select bc.id from org.gokb.cred.BComponent as bc where bc.uuid is null]
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: could not resolve property: uuid of: org.gokb.cred.BComponent [select bc.id from org.gokb.cred.BComponent as bc where bc.uuid is null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: uuid of: org.gokb.cred.BComponent [select bc.id from org.gokb.cred.BComponent as bc where bc.uuid is null]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:671)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:414)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:416)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeFind(HibernateTemplate.java:348)
    ...
```

Why is that? Is my null check incorrect? I've adopted it from similar checks that work fine, like there is:

```
BComponent.executeQuery("select bc.id from BComponent as bc where bc.normname is null and bc.name is not null") // ...
```

Did I forget something? I've already executed

```
$ grails clean
```

What else? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add uuid as a property in my Groovy class code. So:

```
class BComponent{
  // ...
  String uuid
  // ...
}
```

has solved the problem.